# E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)

Tags: partitioning, aws

I have checked if I have hard drive space.

I'm very new at Linux and I'm trying to install updates on my server.

When I execute

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

I instantly get this response

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
```

The second line repeats around 60 times.

when I run `sudo df - h`, I get

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  348K  395M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       24G   14G  9.0G  61% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
```

My understanding is that my drive has 9.0G left but I don't know what the rest of the drives or filesystems are doing?

This is an AWS Ubuntu instance which I just increased in size recently and I have a feeling I'm missing a step to make those 9Gb usable?

Comment: your /tmp is full, so your system cannot create temporary files. Normally `tmp` is a directory under `/`. Unsure why /tmp is mounted as a filesys.

Comment: erm, I didn't setup the server originally. How do I fix this? Are we talking about the overflow or tmpfs ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /tmp folder is used when installing new packages. You have it mapped in a different partition and the size of that partition is only 1M. It gets full very quickly and causes the error.

I would leave the /tmp folder in it's default parition: the same as the / partition (in your case /dev/xvda1).

Have a look at the file `/etc/fstab`. First make a backup copy:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

There is probably a line that mounts the /tmp folder. Add a `#` at the beginning of the line to comment it out. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to save the file and then reboot.

Editing fstab is a potentially dangerous action, be careful if you don't want to have to use the recovery console.

Comment: this is all that's in that file 
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0

Comment: Okay found a way to unmount it sudo umount -l /tmp

Comment: @gavin-mannion: When unmounted, the `/tmp` folder will use the storage of the 9GB again. As shown in the answer, you should check `/etc/fstab` and comment out/remove the line where `/tmp` is mounted. If there is no such line, then you need to figure out what process or script is responsible for the mount.